# Is a Two-Phase Commit initated when Selecting from a remote DB and inserting into a local DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Does SELECTing from a remote database and INSERTing into the local database trigger a two-phase commit?

For example, I want to insert into my local table `foo` all the rows from the remote table `foo@bar`. At no time am I performing an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE on the remote database. Does this initiate a two-phase commit?

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO foo (
       a,
       b,
       c
    ) SELECT a,
        b,
        c
    FROM foo@bar;

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Furthermore, are there any data dictionary views that I can check out to confirm whether or not any transaction performs a two-phase commit?

I tried selecting from `DBA_2PC_PENDING` and `DBA_2PC_NEIGHBORS`, on both the local and remote database, after performing an insert into the remote database and before, during, after the commit, but it returned no rows. The documentation seems to state that these tables are only populated by in-doubt transactions.

Answer (score 2):

No, this statement does not trigger a two-phase commit. It is a remote transaction, it changes data only on the local site. The remote site is read (consistently), but left unchanged. The transaction cannot become in-doubt.

See [Managing Distributed Transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-distributed-transactions.html#GUID-AB19431E-BF9F-4181-BC57-699F8A06149D) and [MOS Note 13229.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=13229.1) (requires an Oracle support account).

The Note 13229.1 describes the difference between remote transaction and distributed transactions as follows:

- A remote transaction contains one or more statements which **all** reference the same remote node.
- A distributed transaction contains statements that modify data in two or more distinct nodes. **The only place where 2-PHASE COMMIT comes into play.**

Comment: Hi @Philipp, I had read that documentation before but don't recall coming across any text that could rule it out. Would you mind quoting the relevant piece of information in your answer?

Comment: I agree @Matthew, the official docs are not very specific in this area. I've edited the answer and included a reference to MOS Note [13229.1: Distributed Database, Transactions and Two Phase Commit](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=13229.1). It explains these concepts very well. You can find additional information in MOS Master Note [1506115.1: Oracle Transaction Management (Local) Overview.](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1506115.1) You need an Oracle support account to access these MOS notes.